# Passing bizRule parameters to RBAC via accessRules?

Tags: php, yii, rbac

From my research I don't think this is possible but I want to make sure. Is it possible to pass parameters to RBAC bizRule via accessRules. Right now I need to check if someone is a post owner (along with other checks) before allowing them to edit/delete a post. So I need to compare the owner_id in the bizRule to verify that `Yii::app()->user->id == param['owner_id']` but I don't think I can pass that param using accessRules? Or can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it.

Different actions are requiring different bizRules. So it will be inefficient to load data for all these prior to any possible action execution.

Answer (score 1):

```
'return yii::app()->user->id==Business::model()->findByPk($_GET["id"])->create_user_id;';
```

this what i give to find the id during updation